# Azure table storage - customer data per day

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

What do you recommend for the following scenario:

If I have in a table 100.000.000 items (a lot of items to be more exact) how can I get those items per day?

Once the items are added into the table, they are not modified or deleted anymore. Basically is just insert and read them.

My question is about retrieving them without having to loop through all 100.000.000 items.

Should I make the PartitionKey a datetime or just date and then retrieve by partionkey where is equal for example 22.10.2013?

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reading the items per day, then using the date (just the Date part, not the full DateTime) as the PartitionKey is the best solution.
When using a Date as the Key, I prefer converting it to a String in the YYYYMMDD (or YYYY-MM-DD) format.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a datetime as a PartitionKey is an anti-pattern since all writes go in the same partition - which limits scalability. The Azure Storage [scalability targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn249410.aspx) indicate that you can do 2,000 operations a second against a partition but 20,000 operations a second against a storage account. You can get round this by sharding inserts across a set of buckets for the day - and prepending the date with the bucket name.

Comment: I mean that not all items 100.000.000 will be inserted at once in the same day. I mentioned 100.000.000 items just as an idea that there will be a lot of items maybe 100 today, maybe 100000 tomorrow and so forth ... so if my partionkey will be like 22.10.2013 I don't see an issue why I cannot use it because will give me just the items with that partition key and maybe for that partion key will be 100.000 items only ..